# How to apply a change of variables in $\int_0^1\int_0^1 \frac{\mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}y}{1-xy}$?

Tags: integration, lebesgue-integral, multiple-integral, fubini-tonelli-theorems

Denote $\mathcal{D}=\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2: 0\le x\le 1 ;\ 0 \le y\le 1   \}$.

I have to use : $x=\cos{\alpha} - t$ and $y=\cos{\alpha}+ t$.

I noticed that $\frac{x+y}{2}=\cos{\alpha}$ and $\frac{y-x}{2}=t$. So I can take $\alpha \in [0, \pi/2]$ and $t\in[-\min\{\ \cos(\alpha) \ ; 1-\cos(\alpha)\ \}, +\min\{\ \cos(\alpha)\ ; 1-\cos(\alpha)\ \}]$.

And now I do not know how to continue. I'm maybe wrong for the $\mathcal{C}^{1}$-diffeomorphism...

Thanks in advance !

Comment: I do not quite understand your change of coordinates. If I plug in $\alpha=\pi/2, t=-1/2$, then I get $x=\cos(\pi/2)-1/2= -1/2$ which is not in $\mathcal{D}$.

Comment: @SeverinSchraven Indeed ... My mistake

Comment: @SeverinSchraven If I take $t\in[-\frac{1}{4}, \frac{1}{4}]$ and $\alpha \in [\frac{\pi}{4},\frac{\pi}{3}]$ ?

Comment: I am super tired right now, will have a look tomorrow

Comment: You have $\cos(\alpha)\in [ 1/2, 1/\sqrt{2}]$ and $t\in [-1/4,1/4]$. This way you get $y=\cos(\alpha) + t\geq 1/2-1/4 = 1/4$. So you will not get all of $\mathcal{D}$.

Comment: @SeverinSchraven Indeed... TY for helping

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't directly answer your question, but I would solve the integral as follows:

$$\int_0^1\int_0^1 \frac{\mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}y}{1-xy} = \int_0^1 \int_0^1 \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(xy)^n~\mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}y =  \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{y^n}{n+1}~dy = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^2} = \frac{\pi^2}{6}.$$

Comment: Although the question doesn't mention it, experience with this integral tells me it's almost certainly only of interest because it can be used to prove $\sum_n1/n^2=\pi^2/6$.